# Is there a way to look up the full list of Cluster Jewel Notables in-game?

Tags: path-of-exile

I am currently using the [forum thread](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2783927) for the Cluster Jewel announcements as a way to check which notable pertains to which, but it is very annoying have to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> over and over just to double check Notables from the trade site. is there any way to actually lookup the Cluster Jewel notables in-game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no list of these notables in-game. You'll have to continue to check the [wiki](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Cluster_Jewel) to get a full list.